# Map Java double to String preserving sort order

Tags: java, double

I am looking for a method `String doubleToString(double d)`, which satisfies the following condition:

For any pair of `double` `d1` and `d2` if `Double.compare(d1, d2) < 0` then  `doubleToString(d1).compareTo(doubleToString(d2)) < 0`.

To illustrate the need, I wrote a similar method for `int` type:

```
public static String intToString(int i) {
    String string = Integer.toHexString(i - Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    return "00000000".substring(string.length()) + string;
}
```

Results (every next `String` is greater than the previous):

```
intToString(-2147483648) = intToString(0x80000000) = "00000000"
intToString(-10)         = intToString(0xfffffff6) = "7ffffff6"
intToString(-1)          = intToString(0xffffffff) = "7fffffff"
intToString(0)           = intToString(0x0)        = "80000000"
intToString(1)           = intToString(0x1)        = "80000001"
intToString(10)          = intToString(0xa)        = "8000000a"
intToString(2147483647)  = intToString(0x7fffffff) = "ffffffff"
```

What I want is to have the same behaving method for `double`'s.

Comment: Can't you `@Override` the string's `.compareTo` to satisfy your requirements?

Comment: could you provide a sample input and expected output?

Comment: Does it have to be readable?

Comment: @biziclop I does not have to be readable, but it would be not bad.

Comment: @BillF no, I cannot override compareTo

Comment: This is trickier than I imagined it to be. :) Of course you can always flatten it out in binary to a zero-padded number that is about 2100 bits long (1/4th of that if you do it in hex), but I guess that's a bit too long.

Comment: What have you written so far? What is your specific question, or is this "SO, please solve this for me!"?

Comment: @BillF `String` is final, you can't override any of its methods.

Comment: @EJP youare right, I was tihinking of `toString` methods. apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the doubles to longs and then use a similar method like you already used for ints. I assume that the following method works as you want (NaN is treated as largest number):

```
public static String doubleToString(double d) {
    final long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(d);
    final String s = Long.toString(bits);
    return (bits < 0 ? "--------------------" : "00000000000000000000").substring(s.length()) + s;
}
```

Example input and output:

```
[-Infinity, -1.7976931348623157E308, -4.9E-324, -0.0, 0.0, 4.9E-324, 1.7976931348623157E308, Infinity]
----4503599627370496
----4503599627370497
-9223372036854775807
-9223372036854775808
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000001
09218868437227405311
09218868437227405312
```

Comment: That's so damn smart!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track but you will need to provide up to 16 leading zeros for the integral part. The fractional part can be arbitrarily long so you can't just use `string.length()` as per your `int` code.

It would be better to keep the collection of doubles as doubles, or `Doubles`, and only convert to String for display or reporting purposes.

Answer (score -1):

It's never no good idea to compare numeric with its string representation.

However - to answer your question - a doubleToString(d1)
is:
String s = String.valueOf(d1);
or simply:
String s = "" + d1;

Comment: This does not satisfy the requirement that the comparison of the string outputs should have the same result as the comparison of the original doubles. (Or to put it more succinctly: the transformation doesn't preserve order.)

Comment: Sorry, now i understand. (Nevertheless: I would compare doubles as doubles)

Comment: Actually, I need it for a text-only database to get correct results for `ORDER BY` queries.